# Change color of the text in navigation bar when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the text of the navigation bar to change color when hover. What's wrong with my codes?

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="pull-left">
        <li><a href="#">Ride</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drive</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">find a city</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sign in</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: for the css part, im not sure when to select 'a' or when to select 'li'

```
.nav a {
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.add {
    color: maroon;    
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav').hover(function() {
        $('a').addClass('add')
    }, function() {
        $('a').removeClass('add')
    });
});
```

THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Why the down vote? The question is valid and clear. Though, it has an easier solution. But for some reasons, easier doesn't mean correct. Maybe for you `5 + 5 = 10` but for him `6 + 4` will do.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Javascript, you can simply use CSS for this:

You can simply try add a css style for nav> a>hover like this:

```
.nav a:hover {
    color: maroon;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lv3tv5no/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!important` to override the color of `a` in `add` class.

```
.add {
     color: maroon !important;
}
```

BTW You can do it using only css like following.

```
.nav:hover a {
    color: maroon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give following way using class.

Because first you have given color on element then you are trying to add color using class. So, it will not replace color of element.

Instead of it give color using class to anchor tag. like here using `.black` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav').hover(function() {
            $('a').addClass('add')
      }, function() {
            $('a').removeClass('add')
      });
});
```

```css
.nav a {
      padding: 14px 10px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: Avenir;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
     
      text-decoration: none;
}

.black{
   color: black;
}

.nav li {
      display: inline;
}

.nav {
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
}

.add {
      color: maroon;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
      <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a class="black" href="#">Ride</a></li>
            <li><a class="black" href="#">Drive</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="pull-right">
           <li><a class="black" href="#">find a city</a></li>
           <li><a class="black" href="#">help</a></li>
           <li><a class="black" href="#">sign in</a></li>
     </ul>
```

**Note:** There is no need of JQuery to change color you can do it using css only. using on **[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)**

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist to use `Jquery` to hover your menus, your `JS` code should be like:

```
$('.nav li a').hover(function(){
    $('li a.add').removeClass('add');
    $(this).addClass('add');
}, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('add');
});
```

Your **[fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/815/)**

**Note:** I used `!important` in `.add` because `color: #000;` was already set your menus in `.nav a`.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Solution:

CSS selectors give you the power to do this. There's no need for Javascript / JQuery.

```
.nav:hover {
    color:maroon;
}
```

### Explaination:

The above code can be broken down into two parts:

- The first is the CSS selector: it selects all elements with a class of `nav`, while they are being hovered on by the user.
- The second is the area inside the brackets. You can change any properties of the element here, and they will change when it is hovered and change back when it isn't.

### CSS Selectors:

Also, here's a definition of some selectors, just to clear up confusion:

- `.nav:hover` selects all `nav` elements that are hovered.
- `.nav a:hover` selects `<a>` tags in the elements with the class of `nav` while they are hovered.
- `.a:hover` selects all `<a>` tags when they are hovered.
- `.nav:hover a` selects all `<a>` tags in an element with a class of `nav` while that element has hover.

Also try `:active` for elements that are being clicked / experiencing a mousedown event.